# Can't get to Porkpatch in FNaF World

Tags: fnaf-world

I went through the ghost block, talked to Fredbear, but I can't figure out where Bubba is inside the Glitched object. Where is he?

Answer (score 1):

When you get in the glitch layer go to where there is two ups then go to the first one and there is a glitch tree. Go in and there is a secret path with a glitch tree on the right and go in. Find your way up and you should be there.